# Use common varible for main project and sub project like "Appdelegate"

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have 2 project one is parent abc.xcodeproj and in sub def.xcodeproj

I need to access my appdelegate variable from abc.xcodeproj project in def.xcodeproj.

any varible or suggestion ?????

Comment: That's not possible. All apps are sandboxed so they can't do things like that. You'll need to store it server side or something else similar.

Comment: Any reason for down voting the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you use the two projects to create just one app (let's say one of them is a library project used in your app), you can get the `AppDelegate` from the main project in your library project using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

If they are different projects for different apps, you can't get the `AppDelegate` from other app